# How to fix build errors in Stride Engine

Tags: visual-studio, stride

I tried building Stride.GameStudio with with Visual Studio 2022, but it failed, with errors.
I tried these steps from the README file.

> Close VS, clear the nuget cache (in your cmd dotnet nuget locals all
> --clear), delete the hidden .vs folder inside \build and the files inside bin\packages,

I got over 3000 errors. So I restored my computer, and started fresh.

Now, when I open the solution, I get this error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error MSB3073 The command
> ""....\core\Stride.Core.Tasks\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows7.0\Stride.Core.Tasks.exe"
> locate-devenv "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64"" exited with code
> 9009. Stride.VisualStudio.Package.Tests   C:\dev\stride-releases-4.1.0.1734\sources\tools\Stride.VisualStudio.Package.Tests\Stride.VisualStudio.Package.Tests.csproj  79

I understand these to be "Invalid path" and "File not found" errors, but I am not sure how to solve them.
How can I fix the error?

Comment: Building for what platform/branch? I see 12 listed (one flagged as failed). What do you mean by 'restored my computer, and started fresh'? Normally I'd take that to mean something like a reinstall / wipe, but that doesn't seem to fit with the remainder of your question.

Comment: Have you followed these steps? https://github.com/stride3d/stride#prerequisites

Comment: You can still just press "Start" in visual studio and it will run. The error is only indicating that a test wasn't compiled, which is ok if you don't need to run all tests.

Comment: Pikalet I meant I used a restore point so as to restore my computer to the state it was previous to the build, thus restoring my nuget packages. >Vaclav Elias yes, I did exactly what was required. >thalm that suggestion sounds reasonable. I will try it in an hour or two. Thanks.

Comment: I decided to scrap Stride, since the build eats all my memory / cpu, which did not happen when I first installed and built the project. It seems like too much of a headache. Not easy to install, as claimed in the README file.